# Temporary file creation using batch script

Tags: batch-file

How to create temporary files like temp1 if condition1 satisfies and temp2 if condition 2 satisfies using windows batch script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
@echo off
set /p "test=Enter 1 or 2 : "

if "%test%"=="1" echo ok >temp1.log
if "%test%"=="2" echo ok >temp2.log
```